# Scaling an Azure Elastic Pool with .NET Fluent API

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elasticpool

I'm using the Azure Fluent API, [Azure Management Libraries for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net), to scale the DTU's within an Azure Elastic Pool and would like to know if it's possible to trigger an update without having to wait for the processing to complete.

Currently the following block of code will wait until the Elastic Pool has finished scaling before it continues execution. With a large premium Elastic Pool this could mean that the this line will take up to 90 minutes to complete.

`ElasticPool
 .Update()
 .WithDtu(1000)
 .Apply();`

There's also a `ApplyAsync()` method which i could deliberately not `await` to allow the program to continue execution, if i take this approach the program will end execution shortly after calling this line and i am unsure if this library has been designed to work in this fashion.

Does anyone know of a better solution to trigger an update without having to wait on a response? Or if it is safe to fire the async method without waiting for a response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to make a fire and forget calls in the Fluent SDK for update scenarios but we are looking to the ways of enabling a manual status polling in the future. One option would be to create a thread that will wait on the completion. The other one is to use the Inner getter and make a low level BeginCreateOrUpdateAsync/BeginUpdateAsync method calls and then do manual polls.

On the side note if you need to make multiple calls and then wait for completion of all of them you can use Task.WaitAll(...) and provide the list of the ApplyAsync tasks.

Please log an issue in the [repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/issues) if you will hit any errors because that way you will be able to track the progress of the fix.

edit: FYI the call is blocking not because SDK is waiting for the response from Azure but that SDK waits until the call is completed, operation of update is finished and the resource is ready to be used for further operations. Just firing an update and then trying to use resource will cause error responses if in your case Elastic Pool is still in the middle of the update.

Comment: Thanks for the response, in the end i've gone down the route of adding a timeout to Task.Wait() so that my program doesn't wait on a response. I'm then using the ListActivities() endpoint to determine when the scaling has completed.